# Deleted items showing up in SharePoint Newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a two month old, single server SharePoint 2013 site collection with several sub sites. Everything is working fine except the Newsfeed shows deleted items from community site discussion posts.

Steps for me to reproduce:

1. Create a new Community Site 
   (example.com/discussions/SitePages/Community%20Home.aspx)
2. Post a new discussion. That post immediately shows up in the Newsfeed
   (example.com/my/default.aspx)
3. Go back to the post and delete it. The post is still in my Newsfeed and the following error is given when it is clicked:

   Server Error in '/' Application.

   Cannot complete this action.

   Please try again.0x80004005

   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

   Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.

   Please try again.0x80004005

   Source Error:

   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

   Stack Trace:

   [COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.

   Please try again.0x80004005]
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFolderContentTypeId(String bstrUrl, String bstrFolderUrl, Object& pvarContentTypeId) +0
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFolderContentTypeId(String bstrUrl, String bstrFolderUrl, Object& pvarContentTypeId) +209

   [SPException: Cannot complete this action.

   Please try again.]
      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +146
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFolderContentTypeId(String bstrUrl, String bstrFolderUrl, Object& pvarContentTypeId) +519
      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetContentTypeIdByUrl(String url) +346
      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewContext.get_FolderContentTypeId() +288
      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewContext.get_NeedToRedirect() +530
      Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewContext.RedirectIfNecessary() +153
      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() +567
      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart.CreateChildControls() +2986
      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartMobileAdapter.CreateChildControls() +129
      System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +166
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +73
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +240
      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4090

Even after waiting several hours, deleted posts are still in the Newsfeed. There are no failed timer jobs in Central Admin and it happens for all users.

Event Log and ULS show similar messages and I can't find any clues why it's happening.

We don't have the problem when we post "Site Feeds". Those immediately disappear from the Newsfeed after deletion.

I have (2) questions: 
Why are deleted posts showing up in the Newsfeed, 
And why isn't SharePoint showing a typical "page not found" when they are clicked?

Comment: Some new information: I noticed that when I delete the community site,  references to the deleted site and previously deleted posts are still in the newsfeed, but when clicked, the links now correctly go to the typical SharePoint page not found page.

Comment: When I un-delete the site, the unhandled COMException is again present when a deleted post link is clicked.